# What ever happened to Jim Darkmagic's inheritance?

Tags: acquisitions-inc

We see that the house that Jim inherited from his grandfather is crashed and spread all over the place; but what happened to the other things he gained? He received the awesome volumes, as well as the chests but they are never mentioned again.